# hdiutil on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, hdiutil

Anyone know of a Linux port of the Mac OS tool hdiutil (http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/hdiutil/)?

Answer (score 8):

`hdiutil` is Apple proprietary software and not part of the public Darwin source code. Since Apple doesn't provide it, a [port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your goal is to boot a linux iso on mac hardware (macbook, ...),
in other words: create a bootable USB drive for mac hardware on linux

in macos, you would use [hdiutil](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271734/how-to-convert-an-iso-file-to-dmg-in-terminal) like

```
hdiutil convert image.iso -format UDRW -o image.dmg
diskutil list # find the USB drive, for example: disk2
N=2
diskutil unmountDisk disk$N
dd if=image.dmg of=/dev/rdisk$N # "rdisk" is faster than "disk"
```

in linux, you can use [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher), which is a graphical tool to "flash OS images to SD cards & USB drives"

note: etcher is closed-source software. maybe you can use a similar tool like  [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

to boot from USB on mac hardware, see [Create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372#use)